# Tensorboard does not display connections in graph

Tags: tensorboard

I run the example `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py` and then open tensorboard with `tensorboard --logdir /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries/`. However, the connections are not displayed, only the nodes are shown, just as the attached snapshot.

[image: tensorboard snapshot]